# Memcached in standalone Docker container time out and port error

Tags: docker, ubuntu, memcached

I'm running a setup of 3 Ubuntu virtual machines. Two running the Python production code base and the other has a Memcached Docker container. On the Memcached machine I ran `docker run -dit --name production-memcached --publish 11211:11211 memcached:latest`.

The code base gets the following error message when trying to interact with it:

> "exception": "TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None)"

I have ran `docker exec -it production-memcached memcached stats` and get the error message below.

> failed to listen on TCP port 11211: Address already in use

However I've ran `netstat -plnt` and get `tcp6 0 0 :::11211 :::* LISTEN 35030/docker-proxy`, which looks fine to me.

I was able to get this to work by opening port 80 and using iptables to forward incoming port 80 to port 11211 but would prefer to use the Memcached port number.

The Memcached client is created by the following line:

`client = base.Client(("domain.co.uk", 11211))`

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DigitalOcean doesn't allow in-traffic on port 11211 to its virtual machines. If you want a Memcached machine you'll also need a virtual machine to act a proxy between you and it. I hope this saves someone the headache it caused me!